# protractor kendo combo box

Tags: javascript, testing, kendo-ui, protractor, webdriverjs

I am having trouble selecting a kendo combobox selection using angular js. The best way i can tell to change the value is to set the model.batch.type on the controller, but i don't know how to do that. I have messed around with executing a script to do it but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label for="type" class="col-sm-1 k-label text-right">Type</label>
    <input id="type" class="col-sm-1 no-padding" kendo-combo-box data-ng-model="model.batch.type"
           k-data-text-field="'name'" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-data-source="model.batchTypes"/>
    <label for="size" class="col-sm-1 k-label text-right">Size</label>
    <input type="text" id="size" name="size" class="col-sm-1 k-textbox" ng-required="true" data-ng-
model="model.batch.size"/>
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 k-label">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="model.barCodePrint" checked/> Print Batch Barcode
    </label>
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="createBatchForm.$invalid"
           value="Create"/>
</div>
```

I am trying to select an option in the second input with id='type'.

Comment: did you got the answer @Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Locate the underlying `input` element, click it, clear, send keys to it and hit enter:

```
var comboBox = element(by.css("input#type")); 

comboBox.click();
comboBox.clear();

combobox.sendKeys("Element inside the combobox");
combobox.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```